# XSL processor stack has overflowed - can't understand why

Tags: xslt, stack-overflow, overflow, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to conditionally display the content of HTML page depending if a document being generated for a recognised company or not.

However, the transformation doesn't work and I can't understand why :( I use MSXML3.0 as transformer and oXygen as IDE, which gives the errors I presented below.

What I do is to construct a long string of all recognised companies (default and extra if any). I then split them into `<token>` elements that are stored in the `$companiesKnownList` variable. To determine if a company is in that list I count how many times it occurs:

```
count($companiesKnownList/token[normalize-space(.) = $productName]) &lt; 1
```

If it's less than 1, then the company doesn't appear in the `$companiesKnownList` variable and therefore is not recognized. Otherwise, if it appears in the `$companiesKnownList` variable once or more times it is a recognized company. Nevertheless, this is where it breaks and displays the following error:

```
Description: Code:   0x80004005
Description: The XSL processor stack has overflowed - probable cause is infinite template recursion.
Description: The transformer process ended with code: 1
```

I've noticed that if my XML has got a recognised company, ex `@ProductName="ski"` then transformation fails with stack overflow. If I have an unrecognized company, ex `@ProductName="bla"` the transformation works and text that it isn't a recognized company is displayed.

I don't understand what's going wrong with valid companies. I would be more than grateful if you could help me out. I have been staring at it for a day now...without any progress :S

Thanks!

**Here is my stylesheet:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="msxsl str"
version="1.0">

<!-- Taken from http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html -->
<xsl:import href="str.tokenize.template.xsl"/>

<!-- normalize and lowcase product name -->
<xsl:variable name="productName"
    select="normalize-space(translate(/Doc/@ProductName, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))"/>

<!-- default recognised companies for all docs -->
<xsl:variable name="defaultRecognisedCompanies" select="'ski, holiday, summer trips'"/>

<!-- Determine what companies to generate a doc for -->
<xsl:variable name="companiesKnownListRaw">
    <xsl:call-template name="recognisedCompanies"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="companiesKnownList" select="msxsl:node-set($companiesKnownListRaw)"/>


<!-- Lists recognised companies for a document to be generated for -->
<xsl:template name="recognisedCompanies">
    <xsl:call-template name="recognisedCompaniesListForDocument"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="recognisedCompaniesListForDocument">
    <xsl:param name="defaultCompanies" select="$defaultRecognisedCompanies"/>
    <xsl:param name="isUseDefaultsCompanies" select="true()"/>
    <xsl:param name="extraCompanies" select="''"/>


    <xsl:variable name="allCompaniesRaw">
        <xsl:call-template name="str:tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="string">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- keep default companies -->
                    <xsl:when test="$isUseDefaultsCompanies = 'true'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($defaultCompanies, ', ', $extraCompanies)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <!-- discard default companies -->
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$extraCompanies"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiters" select="','" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- Normalize token's value and discard empty values -->
    <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($allCompaniesRaw)/token">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) != ''">
            <token>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            </token>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>


<!-- Construct HTML doc. Display appropriate message for a company if it's recognized or not -->
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Doc">
    <html>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Not recognised company -->
            <!-- There is something wrong with the count conditions, and I don't understand what :( -->
            <xsl:when test="count($companiesKnownList/token[normalize-space(.) = $productName]) &lt; 1">
                <body>
                    <div align="center">
                        This type of company is NOT recognised for this document.
                    </div>
                </body>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- Recognised company -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <body>
                    <div align="center">
                        This type of company is recognised for this document.
                    </div>
                </body>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML** is something simple like:

In this example, `ski` is recognized company, but transformation fails.
     `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <Doc ProductName="ski" />`

In this example, `bla` is not a recognized company and transformation succeeds with displaying text: "This type of company is NOT recognised for this document."
     `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <Doc ProductName="bla" />`

Comment: Something is *very wrong* with this question. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the implementation of your named template `str:tokenize`. Check  Jeni Tennison implementation at http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/str.tokenize.template.xsl

Then, add this as stylesheet top element, with correct href:

```
<xsl:include href="str.tokenize.template.xsl"/>
```

With that changes (and closing your last template) with this input:

```
<Doc ProductName="ski" />
```

Ouput:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
                        This type of company is recognised for this document.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Alejandro - thank you for spotting that! I did have that in my original stylesheet - I was trying to simplify it here and missed out the closing tag & import. Silly me doh! Something else has gone wrong then. Thanks again.

Comment: @Alejandro - yes it works for me too. Must be something else that I'm doing within `<body>` (as this example is just text for simplification - I thought something in my logic was wrong before I get to `<body>` tag). Thank you for time looking and answering. I'll check other questions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

MSXML (any version) does not support EXSLT -- and the XSLT processor produces an error message.

Could you, please, correct the question so that only true information is present?

Comment: edit the answer to "MSXML (any version) does not support **EXSLT** "

Comment: @alejandro: Thnks, you saved me. :)